# generate code coverage on JenkinsPipelineUnit tests

Tags: gradle, groovy, jacoco, jenkins-pipeline-unit

I am building a jenkins shared library (in groovy) and testing this with [JenkinsPipelineUnit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit) and in gradle. Running `./gradlew test jacocoTestReport` runs fine, but the report is almost empty (just headers); no coverage is present.

Here are the relevant parts of my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'application'
    id 'jacoco'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'com.lesfurets:jenkins-pipeline-unit:1.1.1-custom' // minor adaptations, but that's another story
}

test {
    systemProperty "pipeline.stack.write", System.getProperty("pipeline.stack.write")
}

jacocoTestReport {
    group = "Reporting"
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
    }
    additionalSourceDirs = files('vars')
    sourceDirectories = fileTree(dir: 'vars')
}
```

I think the trouble resides in the fact that my "source" files reside in the **vars** directory and not in **src/groovy** as expected in a normal groovy project. This is however a requirement for a Jenkins shared library.

I tried specifying

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDir 'vars'
        }
    }
}
```

but then gradle would start compiling this shared library while it's supposed to be loaded upon use; and this breaks everything...

My folder structure looks like this:

```
├── build.gradle
├── src
│   └── test
│       ├── groovy
│       │   └── TestSimplePipeline.groovy
│       └── resources
│           └── simplePipeline.jenkins
└── vars
    ├── MyPipeline.groovy
    └── sh.groovy
```

I think my problem is linked to https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/issues/119 , but I wouldn't know how to use the changes proposed for maven in gradle (not even sure they apply to jacoco).

Comment: JaCoCo performs analysis of bytecode, i.e. class files, whose absence results in empty report. And `classDirectories` not specified in your `jacocoTestReport` task.

Comment: @Godin thanks for this reply. I added `classDirectories = fileTree(dir: 'vars')` into `jacocoTestReport` (just below sourceDirectories); however the test report is still empty...

Comment: According to your description `vars` is a directory with groovy **source** files and not with **class** files.

Comment: yes indeed, would it thus be impossible to get code coverage on a groovy source file?

Comment: To get a coverage on a groovy source files you anyway **must provide class files** to JaCoCo.

Comment: and would this be possible with Cobertura or any other coverage plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `JenkinsPipelineUnit` evaluates your scripts in runtime. It means `jacoco` agent cannot instrument the byte-code generated in runtime.

To overcome this issue you need to do two changes.

1. Use jacoco [offline instrumentalisation](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/offline.html)

In my case I used `maven`, so I cannot provide you with a specific example of a `gradle` configuration.

2. Load compiled classes instead of `groovy` scripts in your test. Something like this:

```
def scriptClass = helper.getBaseClassloader().loadClass("fooScript")
def binding = new Binding()
script = InvokerHelper.createScript(scriptClass, binding)
InterceptingGCL.interceptClassMethods(script.metaClass, helper, binding)
```

Here `fooScript` is the name of the class (say you have a source file called `fooScript.groovy` in this case).

Now you can call methods of this class via

```
def result = script.invokeMethod(methodName, args)
```